# SQL problems when migrating from MySQL to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, group-by

I have a Ruby on Rails 2.3.x application that I'm trying to migrate from my own VPS to Heroku, including porting from SQLite (development) and MySQL (production) to Postgres.

This is a typical Rails call I'm using:

```
spots = Spot.paginate(:all, :include => [:thing, :user, :store, {:thing => :tags}, {:thing => :brand}], :group => :thing_id, :order => order, :conditions => conditions, :page => page, :per_page => per_page)
```

**Question 1:** I get a lot of errors like `PG::Error: ERROR:  column "spots.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`. SQLite/MySQL was evidently more forgiving here. Of course I can easily fix these by adding the specified fields to my `:group` parameter, but I feel I'm messing up my code. Is there a better way?

**Question 2:** If I throw in all the GROUP BY columns that Postgres is missing I end up with the following statement (only `:group` has changed):

```
spots = Spot.paginate(:all, :include => [:thing, :user, :store, {:thing => :tags}, {:thing => :brand}], :group => 'thing_id,things.id,users.id,spots.id', :order => order, :conditions => conditions, :page => page, :per_page => per_page)
```

This in turn produces the following SQL code:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON ("spots".id) "spots".id, spots.created_at AS alias_0 FROM "spots"  
LEFT OUTER JOIN "things" ON "things".id = "spots".thing_id 
WHERE (spots.recommended_to_user_id = 1 OR spots.user_id IN (1) OR things.is_featured = 't')  
GROUP BY thing_id,things.id,users.id,spots.id) AS id_list 
ORDER BY id_list.alias_0 DESC LIMIT 16 OFFSET 0;
```

...which produces the error `PG::Error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "users"`. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4):

#### Question 1:

...Is there a better way?

Yes. Since PostgreSQL 9.1 the primary key of a table logically covers all columns of a table in the `GROUP BY` clause. I quote the [release notes for version 9.1](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/release-9-1.html):

> Allow non-GROUP BY columns in the query target list when the primary
>   key is specified in the GROUP BY clause (Peter Eisentraut)

#### Question 2:

The following statement ... produces the error

> PG::Error: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "users"

How can I solve this?

First (as always!), I formatted your query to make it easier to understand. The culprit has bold emphasis:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (spots.id)
          spots.id, spots.created_at AS alias_0
   FROM   spots  
   LEFT   JOIN things ON things.id = spots.thing_id 
   WHERE (spots.recommended_to_user_id = 1 OR
          spots.user_id IN (1) OR
          things.is_featured = 't')  
   GROUP  BY thing_id, things.id, users.id, spots.id
   ) id_list 
ORDER  BY id_list.alias_0 DESC
LIMIT  16
OFFSET 0;
```

It's all obvious now, right?
Well, not *all* of it. There is a lot more. `DISTINCT ON` and `GROUP BY` in the same query for one, which has its uses, but not here. **Radically simplify** to:

```
SELECT s.id, s.created_at AS alias_0
FROM   spots s
WHERE  s.recommended_to_user_id = 1 OR
       s.user_id = 1 OR
       EXISTS (
          SELECT 1 FROM things t
          WHERE  t.id = s.thing_id
          AND    t.is_featured = 't')
ORDER  BY s.created_at DESC
LIMIT  16;
```

The [`EXISTS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) semi-join avoids the later need to `GROUP BY` a priori. This should be much faster (besides being correct) - if my assumptions about the missing table definitions hold.

Comment: Thanks, but do I need to recode all my queries to pure SQL, or can I still use `Spot.paginate`?

Comment: @TomSöderlund: I am no expert with Ruby, don't know about `spot.paginate`. The new query is much simpler than the old one. `EXISTS` is very basic standard SQL ...

Answer (score 0):

Going the "pure SQL" route opened up a can of worms for me, so I tried keeping the will_paginate gem and tweak the `Spot.paginate` parameters instead. The `:joins` parameter turned out to be very helpful.

This is currently working for me:

```
spots = Spot.paginate(:all, :include => [:thing, {:thing => :tags}, {:thing => :brand}], :joins => [:user, :store, :thing], :group => 'thing_id,things.id,users.id,spots.id', :order => order, :conditions => conditions, :page => page, :per_page => per_page)
```